# Compact generation of the infinity category of stable infinity categories

Tags: infinity-categories

I am reading the paper "[A universal characterization of higher algebraic K-theory](https://arxiv.org/abs/1001.2282)" by Blumberg, Gepner, and Tabuada, and I am stuck on Corollary 4.25:

> …the fact that we have accessible localizations provides the following corollary about the
> structure of $\mathrm{Cat}_\infty^\mathrm{ex}$ and $\mathrm{Cat}_\infty^\mathrm{perf}$.

> Corollary 4.25. The ∞-categories $\mathrm{Cat}_\infty^\mathrm{ex}$ and $\mathrm{Cat}_\infty^\mathrm{perf}$ are compactly generated, complete, and cocomplete.

Here, $\mathrm{Cat}_\infty^\mathrm{ex}$ (resp. $\mathrm{Cat}_\infty^\mathrm{perf}$) is the ∞-category of small stable ∞-categories (resp. of small idempotent-complete stable ∞-categories).

The "accessible localizations" they are referring to are Theorem 4.22 and Theorem 4.23, which state that $\mathrm{Cat}_\infty^\mathrm{ex}$ and $\mathrm{Cat}_\infty^\mathrm{perf}$ are accessible localizations of the ∞-category of small spectral categories.

My thought is as follows: Dugger's theorem shows that the ∞-category of small spectral categories can be modelled by a combinatorial simplicial model category, so it is presentable.  Therefore $\mathrm{Cat}_\infty^\mathrm{ex}$ and $\mathrm{Cat}_\infty^\mathrm{perf}$ are presentable.  However, I cannot see how to prove that they are $\omega$-accessible, i.e. compactly generated.  Can anyone help me fill in this gap?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Proposition 4.20 in the same paper shows that the localization is in fact $\omega$-accessible, i.e. the fully faithful right adjoint in question preserves filtered colimits. This implies that the localized category is $\omega$-accessible, in particular compactly generated (because the category you're localizing from is compactly generated)

Alternatively, you can observe that the forgetful functor $Cat^{ex}_\infty\to Cat_\infty$ preserves filtered colimits and arbitrary limits, and that therefore its left adjoint preserves compacts. Because this forgetful functor is furthermore conservative, the claim also follows.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. This may be a dumb question, but can you tell me why the ∞-category of spectral categories is compactly generated?

Comment: This is not a dumb question at all, and in fact not having to think about this is the reason I put the "alternatively" part of my answer :) I think to prove this you need to go deeper into the references that show that it is a combinatorial model category. Specifically, if you look at Corollary 2.4 in that paper, it gives an explicit set of generators, which I suppose you can check are compact (although you have to prove that the Bousfield localization that's involved is also compact-preserving, but this should follow from the weak equivalences being stable under filtered colimits or something

Comment: The bottom line is: I'm not sure, and this is why I put the second half of my answer there

Comment: Thank you so much!  I never imagined there would be so much between the lines on that paper, but I will attempt to prove it in the way you suggest.  The alternative argument was also very helpful.